# Athena aggregate calculated rows to an array

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, array-agg

I have the following SQL that produces a list of values:

```
SELECT x / 100e0 FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 100, 1)) t(x)
```

| # | _col0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.01 |
| 2 | 0.02 |
| 3 | 0.03 |
| ... | ... |
| 100 | 1 |

I'm trying to aggregate the results to get an array of `[0.01,0.02,0.03,,,,,1.0]` as follows without success, what am I missing?

```
SELECT array_agg(x / 100e0 FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 100, 1)) t(x))
```

Error:

```
mismatched input 'FROM'. Expecting: ',', <expression>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Amazon Athena, but it looks like you misplaced the closing brace. Try this one `SELECT array_agg(x / 100e0) FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 100, 1)) t(x)`

Comment: Boom ... thanks that was it :)